# Can slicing be performed with Lists in Scala just like in Python or R?

Tags: scala, list, slice

Suppose I have the following string and converted it to List[Char]

```
    val y: String = "what's up?"
    val z = y.toList
```

Now, I would like to access 4th to 7th element of the above list:

Desired output:

```
    res: List(t,',s, )
```

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice`:

```
scala> z.slice(3,7)
res1: List[Char] = List(t, ', s,  )
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that you don't need to convert the String to a List[Char], y.slice(3,7) will work just fine too.

Comment: Great! I just started with Scala. Is there any best way to search for methods to objects? Thanks again!

Comment: @Ash Usually, googling something like "scaladoc api 2.12" brings you to the [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/) sooner or later, from there, just enter the name of the class in the "search". Also note that `String` is actually just Java's `String`, some of the rich API methods are available over implicit conversions, e.g. [`StringOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html).

Comment: @Andrey Thanks for the tips!